# Python Selenium: element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "v") doesn't work in headless mode?

Tags: python, selenium

Env: Ubuntu 16.04
`selenium` driver: Chrome

In non-headless mode, `element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "v")` perfectly paste the text from the clipboard.

But when I rerun the same code with headless Chrome,

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

It doesn' work. I saved a screenshot of the screen so that I could check whether any text is typed but it didn't!

What's wrong with headless mode?

Comment: In headless mode there's no access to the OS clipboard in Chrome.

Comment: Oops, then no solution exists to use clipboard in headless mode?

Comment: why using clipboard not variable?

Comment: @user3595632 Your code trials with `element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "v")`?

Comment: I wonder if it's actually the paste that doesn't work, or there's nothing in clipboard to paste. How do you know there's anything in clipboard to paste? can you post a code fragment that copies and pastes?